# In App Purchase not working on iPhone 3,4

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

on iphone 5 all is good but on iPhone 3,4 i get transaction failed state after pressing the but button of the purchase...
i have try almost everything but always the same problem, if you had the same problem and you know the answer please help it takes less than a minute ;) thanks!

```
    -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:{
                // show wait view here
                NSLog(@"Processing...");
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:{
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view and unlock feature 2
                NSLog(@"DONE!");

                [prefs setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"payed"];
                self.buyButton.hidden = TRUE;
                [self getData:@"yes"];
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:{
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled2");
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:{
                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled1:%@",transaction.error.description);
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            }
            default:{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}






-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    // remove wait view here
    //statusLabel.text = @"";

    int count = [response.products count];

    if (count>0) {
        SKProduct *validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

        //SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:validProduct];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:validProduct];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

    } else {
      // no products found
    }


}

-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
{

}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}



#pragma mark AlertView Delegate
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex);

    if (alertView==askToPurchase) {
        if (buttonIndex==1) {
            // user tapped YES, but we need to check if IAP is enabled or not.
            if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {

                SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.adam.CrowdControl.adamProduct1"]];

                request.delegate = self;
                [request start];


            } else {
                UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Prohibited"
                                    message:@"Parental Control is enabled, cannot make a purchase!"
                                    delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
                [tmp show];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is relevant with the model of phones.

Is the app on sandbox mode? If it is, there must not be any iTunes account saved on the phone. Log out from your accounts on each phone. You can "only" test successfully with "Test User" account that you created in iTunes Connect.

I assume that you made all the arrangements in iTunes Connect about IAP, added products vs. Because you said that it's working on one phone.

Answer (score -1):

Did you submitted a version of your app to apple ? You need to submit it, with your in-app store items selected and then reject it (since is not yet the final version).
 Also, allow some time after that (12 hours or so, since I've seen sometimes there is a long delay).
 One more thing, use US test accounts and items submitted for US store (I remember anything else failing on a past project).